# Webpack - package: @babel/polyfill has been deprecated - How to use an alternative?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I came back to my Webpack 4 configuration and all the packages after 4 months. It always surprises me how fast a package get's updated or deprecated.

I have this problem, that I used to include the @babel/polyfill directly to the Webpack's entry => src together with my other JS and SASS source.

This is my current .babelrc file:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "useBuiltIns": "entry",
                "corejs": "core-js@2",
                "debug": false
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

And my Webpack's entry setting:

```
entry: {
    src: [paths.entry.polyfill(), paths.entry.js(), paths.entry.sass()]
},
```

And the config where i setup all the exports:

```
entry: {
    sass: () => path.resolve(module.exports.sass(), './style.scss'),
    js: () => path.resolve(module.exports.js(), './index.js'),
    polyfill: () => '@babel/polyfill'
},
```

My package.json with the Babel files:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
"@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
"autoprefixer": "^9.4.4",
"babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
```

Is there any replacement that i can use for the @babel/polyfill as of today?

I would like to keep a polyfill but replace it with the deprecated package.

Thanks!

EDIT:

JS file causing an error for some reason Arrow functions are not working in production mode only:

```
(() => {
    // Do not remove this console log. It serves as a reminder to build in production mode.
    // Building in production mode removes all console, alert and debug statements.
    // NM.
    console.log(
        '%c Running main script in development mode.',
        'color: #bada55; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 700'
    );

    // Add class top HTML tag if a mobile device is detected.
    const primaryHTML = document.querySelector('html');

    if (
        /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(
            navigator.userAgent
        )
    ) {
        primaryHTML.classList.add('touchdevice');
    }
})();
```

Webpack file:

```
require('checkenv').check();

// Webpack Setup
const { THEME_AUTHOR, THEME_NAME, HOST, PORT } = require('./env.config');

const path = require('path');
const paths = require('./paths.config');
const pkg = require('../package.json');
const webpack = require('webpack');

// Plugins
const HappyPack = require('happypack');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer')
    .BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const HardSourceWebpack = require('hard-source-webpack-plugin');
const BrowserSync = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtract = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const styleLint = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpack = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ExtraWatchWebpackPlugin = require('extra-watch-webpack-plugin');
const FriendlyErrorsPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackBuildNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-build-notifier');
const CleanTerminalPlugin = require('clean-terminal-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const Imagemin = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default;
const threadPool = HappyPack.ThreadPool({ size: 4 });

// Config utils
const { removeEmpty, getIfUtils } = require('webpack-config-utils');
const { NODE_ENV } = process.env;
const { ifProduction, ifDevelopment } = getIfUtils(NODE_ENV);

module.exports = {
    target: 'web',
    mode: ifDevelopment ? 'development' : 'production',

    stats: {
        hash: false,
        version: false,
        timings: false,
        assets: false,
        chunks: false,
        modules: false,
        reasons: false,
        children: false,
        source: false,
        errors: false,
        builtAt: false,
        errorDetails: false,
        entrypoints: false,
        warnings: false,
        publicPath: false
    },

    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
    },

    optimization: {
        minimize: ifProduction(true, false),
        namedModules: ifDevelopment(true, false),
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        noEmitOnErrors: true,
        splitChunks: {
            hidePathInfo: true,
            chunks: 'all',
            automaticNameDelimiter: '-',
            maxAsyncRequests: 5,
            maxInitialRequests: 3,
            name: THEME_NAME,
            cacheGroups: {
                style: {
                    enforce: true,
                    priority: 1
                },
                vendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    priority: 2,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    enforce: true,
                    chunks: 'all'
                }
            }
        },

        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                uglifyOptions: {
                    parallel: true,
                    cache: false,
                    warnings: false,
                    comments: false,
                    compress: {
                        drop_console: ifProduction(true, false)
                    },
                    output: {
                        comments: false
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
    },

    entry: {
        src: [paths.entry.js(), paths.entry.sass()]
    },

    output: {
        path: paths.output.base(),
        filename: paths.filename.js()
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['happypack/loader?id=js']
            },

            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: [MiniCssExtract.loader, 'happypack/loader?id=scss']
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: removeEmpty([
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            // Write Logs to Console
            verbose: ifDevelopment(true, false),

            // Automatically remove all unused webpack assets on rebuild
            cleanStaleWebpackAssets: true,

            // Do not allow removal of current webpack assets
            protectWebpackAssets: false
        }),

        new ExtraWatchWebpackPlugin({
            files: ['.stylelintrc', '.stylelintignore', '.eslintrc']
        }),

        new HappyPack({
            id: 'js',
            verbose: ifDevelopment(true, false),
            threadPool: threadPool,
            loaders: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
        }),

        new HappyPack({
            id: 'scss',
            verbose: ifDevelopment(true, false),
            threadPool: threadPool,
            loaders: [
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        url: false,
                        modules: false
                    }
                },
                'sass-loader'
            ]
        }),

        new styleLint({
            configFile: '.stylelintrc',
            context: paths.sass(),
            files: '**/*.s?(a|c)ss'
        }),

        new MiniCssExtract({
            filename: paths.filename.sass()
        }),

        new CopyWebpack([
            {
                from: paths.images(),
                to: paths.output.images()
            }
        ]),

        new CopyWebpack([
            {
                from: paths.fonts(),
                to: paths.output.fonts()
            }
        ]),

        ifProduction(
            new Imagemin({
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i
            })
        ),

        new HardSourceWebpack.ExcludeModulePlugin([
            {
                // HardSource works with mini-css-extract-plugin but due to how
                // mini-css emits assets, assets are not emitted on repeated builds with
                // mini-css and hard-source together. Ignoring the mini-css loader
                // modules, but not the other css loader modules, excludes the modules
                // that mini-css needs rebuilt to output assets every time.
                test: /mini-css-extract-plugin[\\/]dist[\\/]loader/
            },
            {
                test: /my-loader/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'vendor')
            }
        ]),

        new HardSourceWebpack({
            environmentHash: {
                root: process.cwd(),
                directories: [],
                files: ['package-lock.json', 'yarn.lock']
            },

            info: {
                mode: 'none',
                level: 'debug'
            },

            // Clean up large, old caches automatically.
            cachePrune: {
                // Caches younger than `maxAge` are not considered for deletion. They must
                // be at least this (default: 2 days) old in milliseconds.
                maxAge: 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                // All caches together must be larger than `sizeThreshold` before any
                // caches will be deleted. Together they must be at least this
                // (default: 50 MB) big in bytes.
                sizeThreshold: 50 * 1024 * 1024
            }
        }),

        new BrowserSync(
            {
                proxy: HOST,
                open: false,
                notify: false,
                port: PORT,
                files: [
                    'wp-content/themes/**/*.css',
                    {
                        match: ['wp-content/themes/**/*.php']
                    }
                ],
                snippetOptions: {
                    ignorePaths: ['wp-admin/**', 'wp-content/**']
                }
            },

            {
                reload: false
            }
        ),

        new FriendlyErrorsPlugin(),

        // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
        //     openAnalyzer: false,
        //     generateStatsFile: false,
        //     statsOptions: {
        //         exclude: /node_modules/,
        //         errors: false,
        //         warnings: false,
        //         errorDetails: false,
        //         reasons: false,
        //         cached: false,
        //         cachedAssets: false
        //     }
        // }),

        new CleanTerminalPlugin(),

        new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),

        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV),
            'process.env.VERSION': JSON.stringify(pkg.version)
        }),

        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(true),

        new webpack.BannerPlugin({
            banner: `Copyright ${new Date().getFullYear()} ${THEME_AUTHOR} - v${
                pkg.version
            }`,
            exclude: /(main-vendor|main-runtime)\.js/i
        }),

        ifDevelopment(new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin()),

        ifDevelopment(
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                exclude: /(main-vendor|main-runtime)\.js/i
            })
        ),

        ifDevelopment(
            new WebpackBuildNotifierPlugin({
                title: `${THEME_AUTHOR}`,
                sound: false,
                suppressSuccess: true
            })
        )
    ])
};
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

core-js is currently replacing bable-polyfill. You do not have to set it anywhere except for the .babelrc file
I have a question, why do you duplicate libraries you have `@babel/polyfill` and `babel-pollyfill`
the same applies to `@babel/preset-env` and `babel-preset-en`. You have declared in `.babelrc` `corejs` but I do not see that `package.json` has been installed?

My [example](https://github.com/tomik23/ToDoList/blob/master/package.json#L12) may not be perfect but I try to strive for it :)

`.babelrc`

```
{
 "presets": [
   [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    {
     "useBuiltIns": "usage",
     "corejs": 3
    }
   ]
  ]
}
```

`package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
  "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
  "core-js": "^3.1.4" // this is now your polyfill
  ...
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
entry: {
  app: './index.js',
},
```

`index.js`

```
import './style.scss';
import module from './module.js';
...
```

**UPDATE**

add to `package.json`, you can prepare your own list of supported browsers

```
"browserslist": [
  "last 2 version",
  ">1%",
  "not dead"
],
```

add to `.babelrc`

```
{
  "debug": true,
  "useBuiltIns": "usage",
  "corejs": 3
}
```

After all these additional changes in the console will appear what browsers are supported and what pollyfill have been added. And of course the most important thing is to test it in IE11. I always test on 6-7 desktop and 3-4 mobile browsers.

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a try make some changes and let you know.

Comment: One more question and I will accept your answer. I am usually implementing babel-polyfill inside Webpack entries. How can I be sure that core-js will work in IE11? is this an alternative?

Comment: Great, the only issue I am having now with the .babelrc changed. Is that when I run a production mode using arrow functions I am getting an error:  error  

js/prestigexotics.min.95986a5013220aeae32a.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: punc «)» [js/prestigexotics.min.95986a5013220aeae32a.js:17,2]

Comment: Do you have the code for this prestigexotics.js file somewhere?

Comment: Sure, let me edit my answer. It's not like I am a newbie but sometimes Webpack is giving me a headache. Let me show you the file. and my Webpack file.

Comment: AHA! .browserslistrc was causing it! # Browsers that we support

[development]
> 5% in NL
last 2 versions
not ie <= 11
not dead
maintained node versions

[production]
> 2% in NL
last 2 edge version
last 2 safari version
last 2 chrome version
last 2 firefox version
last 2 samsung version
not ie 11
maintained node versions

production missing not dead.

Comment: I'm just testing and it looks like it has nothing to do with the js file. I imported it into my project and everything works. I am checking the optimization configuration and there is a problem because my environment does not want to work with my settings.

Comment: I have figured it out Grzegorz, my .browserslistrc in production mode was missing the "not dead" value. Thank you very much my friend.

Comment: Move browserlist to package.js is better managed than the next file in my opinion :)
All the latest framworki certainly vue, reactjs and most likely angular have this entry in package.json

Comment: Does it have any benefits? I have also noticed that create React App does that to when i work on a React project.

Comment: Such a smaller mess in the files and less probability of error.

Comment: I just wanted to say a big thanks to @Galanthus. I've been looking for a setup that worked with the new way of using core-js for days, and this one finally worked!

Answer (score 1):

**UPD**

In the case with webpack 5:

> Turn off ES2015 syntax in runtime code, if necessary
>
> By default, webpack's runtime code uses ES2015 syntax to build smaller
> bundles. If your build targets environments that don't support this
> syntax (like IE11), you'll need to set target: ['web', 'es5'] to
> revert to ES5 syntax ('web' if target environment is browser).

The [source](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/#turn-off-es2015-syntax-in-runtime-code-if-necessary).