# Babel polyfill not working for IE 11 (Object doesn't support property or method 'assign')

Tags: webpack, babel-polyfill

It's been a while since we tested our app on IE 11 and now the polyfill is not working in IE and getting the error `Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'`.

Some updates have been made to our libraries/packages, but I'm not sure if that's the reason why it's not working. Below are my webpack and babel/package.json config files.

webpack.base.js

```
const path = require('path')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = options => {
    let envPath = '.env'
    process.argv.forEach(val => {
        if (val.includes('--env=')) {
            const curEnv = val.slice(6)
            if (['dev', 'stg', 'prod'].includes(curEnv)) {
                envPath = `.env.${curEnv}`
            }
        }
    })
    return {
        mode: options.mode,
        devServer: options.devServer,
        entry: [path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/main.js')],
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, '../dist/'),
            publicPath: '/',
            filename: '[name].[hash].js',
            chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].js'
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
            modules: [
                path.join(__dirname, '../src'),
                path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
            ],
            alias: {
                '@constants': path.join(__dirname, '../src/constants'),
                '@c': path.join(__dirname, '../src/components'),
                '@C': path.join(__dirname, '../src/containers')
            }
        },
        plugins: options.plugins.concat([
            new Dotenv({
                path: path.join(process.cwd(), envPath)
            }),
            new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
                inject: true,
                template: path.join(__dirname, '../src/static/index.html'),
                favicon: path.join(__dirname, '../src/static/favicon.ico')
            })
        ]),
        module: {
            rules: options.module.rules.concat([
                // {
                //  enforce: 'pre',
                //  test: /\.jsx?$/,
                //  exclude: /node_modules/,
                //  use: [
                //      {
                //          loader: 'eslint-loader',
                //          options: {
                //              quiet: true
                //          }
                //      }
                //  ]
                // },
                {
                    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                    exclude: [ /\.scss$/ ],
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: {
                                name: '[hash].[ext]',
                                outputPath: 'fonts'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.svg$/,
                    loader: 'svg-react-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/i,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'url-loader',
                            options: {
                                limit: 10 * 1024,
                                name: '[hash].[ext]',
                                outputPath: 'assets'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                            options: {
                                disable: options.mode === 'development'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

webpack.prod.js

```
const path = require('path');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = require('./webpack.base')({
    mode: 'production',
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        contentBase: path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist/')
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                cache: true,
                parallel: true
            }),
            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin()
        ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules\/@babel/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                                {
                                    'targets': {
                                        'ie': '11'
                                    },
                                    'loose': true,
                                    'forceAllTransforms': true,
                                    'debug': true
                                }
                            ],
                            '@babel/preset-react'
                        ],
                        sourceType: 'unambiguous',
                        plugins: [
                          [
                              '@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators',
                              {
                                  'legacy': true
                              }
                          ],
                          [
                            'react-css-modules',
                            {
                              "filetypes": {
                                ".scss": { "syntax": "postcss-scss" }
                              },
                              "generateScopedName": '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
                            }
                          ],
                          '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
                          '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
                          '@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind',
                          '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
                          '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from',
                          '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from'
                        ]
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            sourceMap: true,
                            localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin([path.join(process.cwd(), '/dist')], {
            allowExternal: true
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[hash].css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].css'
        }),
        new CompressionPlugin({
            test: /\.(js|css)$/,
            filename: asset => asset.file
        })
    ]
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "plaympe-web",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "PlayMPE",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --env=dev",
    "start:stg": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --env=stg",
    "start:prod": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --env=prod",
    "build:dev": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --env=dev",
    "build:stg": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --env=stg",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --env=prod",
    "deploy:dev": "node scripts/deploy.js --env=dev",
    "deploy:stg": "node scripts/deploy.js --env=stg",
    "deploy:prod": "node scripts/deploy.js --env=prod",
    "profile": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.profile.js --progress --profile --colors",
    "profile:stats": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.profile.js --profile --json > ./stats/webpack-build-stats.json",
    "formatsvg": "svgo -f ./src/images/icons --enable=inlineStyles,removeAttrs  --config '{ \"plugins\": [ { \"inlineStyles\": { \"onlyMatchedOnce\": false } }, { \"removeAttrs\": { \"attrs\": \"filter\" } } ] }' --pretty",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.js\" prettier --write \"**/*.jsx\"",
    "eslint": "eslint --quiet ./src"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults",
    "IE >= 9",
    "iOS >= 6",
    "Safari >= 6",
    "Firefox >= 45"
  ],
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "ie": "11"
          },
          "loose": true,
          "forceAllTransforms": true,
          "debug": true
        }
      ],
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "sourceType": "unambiguous",
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
        {
          "legacy": true
        }
      ],
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.6.3",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^5.2.6",
    "branch-sdk": "^2.52.3",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "detect-browser": "^4.7.0",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "i18next": "^17.0.4",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^3.0.1",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^3.0.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.0.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "localforage": "^1.7.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "num-words": "^1.0.1",
    "postcss-scss": "^2.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "query-string": "^6.8.3",
    "rc-slider": "^8.6.13",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^12.1.1",
    "react-div-100vh": "^0.3.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-i18next": "^10.11.2",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^5.0.4",
    "react-notifications-component": "^1.1.1",
    "react-popper": "^1.3.4",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-spinkit": "^3.0.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reduxsauce": "^1.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^1.2.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.4.3",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.383.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.5.7",
    "eslint": "^5.10.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^4.6.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.1.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.7",
    "s3-easy-deploy": "^1.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^2.2.0",
    "svg-react-loader": "^0.4.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.0.1",
    "tailwindcss-aspect-ratio": "^2.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "^0.1.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of @babel/polyfill you can try using core-js
You can also install @babel/plugin-transform-object-assign

Comment: Where should I put that in my config?

Comment: In addition to an error on Object.assign, I'm getting errors for `findIndex`. Is there a way to polyfill everything at once?

Comment: How and where should I config core-js?

Comment: Take a look at this post [react-app-polyfill](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-app-polyfill).
And here is an example of how to use core-js in [webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57192049/10424385) or this https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html